# Is my molecular gastronomy question too subjective for the site?

Tags: discussion

I wasn't sure if my latest question, [How can I integrate molecular gastronomy in to regular cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6434/how-can-i-integrate-molecular-gastronomy-in-to-regular-cooking), was on topic? I battled a little bit on whether to ask it. It seems pretty subjective and kind of discussion-y. Is this an appropriate use for community wiki? Per Aaronut's recent comment about the reason for CW, it seems I've been misunderstanding the purpose of that tool. Incidentally, it only took about 10 minutes for the question to receive 4 upvotes and 4 favorites.

Is the question ok?
Is the question less likely to be closed because I have a high user rep?
Is there a way that I can make this question better?

Comment: I thought it was a good question when it appeared in my feed reader before I even saw it was associated with your account yossarian.

Answer (score 4):

For my taste, it is a perfectly good question. It might end up spawning additional, more detailed questions, but it is a fine starting point. It is list-y so I think CW is right, but has a set of valid answers. And even more interesting because the answers are evolving every day.

Comment: +1: Nothing else to add.

Comment: Yes, +1. It will either become a bit more specific (which I requested) or as michael said, will spawn good spin-off.